# Sandboxie and fall-through programs

Tags: windows-10, sandboxie

I have an application that needs connection to the server while running.
The application contains 3 files: A.exe, B.exe and C.abs.

The application starts when the user clicks B.exe which will call up A.exe for log-in. If the credentials are ok then B is called, which in turn calls C with specific hex tokens added e.g. "C.abs 0xDEADBEEF" (observable in task manager's command-line column if not using sandbox).

Now Sandboxie always reports an error that C has crashed even if A and B are running. Process C is of course not present in the Box. However, after 7 minutes after B has loaded, the application crashes and A is displayed again for signon.

Comment: Does it work outside of the sandbox?

Comment: What restrictions are defined for the sandbox?

Comment: @DavidPostill, yes it does. The dev team report to their managers that it doesn't, though. I guess they want to have more work to do, not really OS or platform issues.

Comment: @harrymc, I set no restrictions for the box to run them.

Comment: Some programs just don't work in Sandboxie.